# Unity3D and QCAR project "Unable to find QCARWrapper" error after importing to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unity-game-engine, qcar-sdk

I made a Unity3D+QCAR project and tried to import it into eclipse, but when I run the apk on my mobile I get the error "Unable to find QCARWrapper" on LogCat and the camera is not activated.

Do you have any clue of how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.